# 年齢を区間ごとにダミー変数化したい

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

初めまして、Pythonおよびデータ分析初心者です。主にPandasとNumpy,Sklearnを使ってkaggle等のコンペに挑戦している最中の者です。

データセットをロジスティック回帰によって分析したいのですが、質的データであればpd.getdummies()で簡単にダミー変数を作ることができることを最近学びました。しかし年齢のように現在扱っているデータもを区画ごとにダミー変数化する必要があると考えて調べているのですが、なかなか良い方法が探せずに居ます。具体的には年齢に対して0-20,20-40,40-60,60-　という新しい列を作り、それに該当するか否かで0,1の値を割り振りたいと考えています。

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

ID = np.arange(1,101) 
#ID.shape
Age = np.random.randint(0,100,100)
#Age.shape

DF = pd.DataFrame([ID,Age]).T
DF.columns = ["ID","Age"]
#DF
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このようなテーブルに対して、以下のような変換方法はございませんでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Pythonやデータ分析に関して何かご知見ございましたら、お答えいただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下は [numpy.searchsorted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) を使う方法です。

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'ID': range(1, 7),
  'Age': [13, 8, 92, 86, 26, 96]
}, dtype=int)

bins = range(0, 61, 20)
binned = np.searchsorted(bins, df.Age.values) - 1
data = np.zeros((len(df), len(bins)), dtype=int)
data[np.arange(len(df)), binned] = 1

columns = ['ID'] + \
  [f'Age({s+1 if s>0 else s}, {e})' for s, e in zip(bins, bins[1:])] + \
  [f'Age({bins[-1]+1}-)']

dfn = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([df.ID, data]), columns=columns)

print(dfn)

   ID  Age(0, 20)  Age(21, 40)  Age(41, 60)  Age(61-)
0   1           1            0            0         0
1   2           1            0            0         0
2   3           0            0            0         1
3   4           0            0            0         1
4   5           0            1            0         0
5   6           0            0            0         1
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。searchSortedは近い値を返すといったものでしょうか。参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 0):

ややアドホックですが、

```
dummy_df["Age[21:41]"] = df.apply(lambda row: int(row.Age >= 21 and row.Age < 41), axis=1)
```

のように使いたい条件式を使ってそれぞれの列の 0, 1 を計算するのは如何でしょうか。今回は列の数も少ないのでこんな感じで良さそうです。

以下、完全なコード例です。

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> age = np.random.randint(0,100,100)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(age, columns=["Age"])
>>> df
    Age
0    29
1    86
2    79
3    80
4    77
..  ...
95   53
96   11
97   14
98   89
99   75

[100 rows x 1 columns]
>>> dummy_df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> dummy_df["Age[:21]"] = df.apply(lambda row: int(row.Age < 21), axis=1)
>>> dummy_df["Age[21:41]"] = df.apply(lambda row: int(row.Age >= 21 and row.Age < 41), axis=1)
>>> dummy_df["Age[41:61]"] = df.apply(lambda row: int(row.Age >= 41 and row.Age < 61), axis=1)
>>> dummy_df["Age[61:]"] = df.apply(lambda row: int(row.Age >= 61), axis=1)
>>> dummy_df
    Age[:21]  Age[21:41]  Age[41:61]  Age[61:]
0          0           1           0         0
1          0           0           0         1
2          0           0           0         1
3          0           0           0         1
4          0           0           0         1
..       ...         ...         ...       ...
95         0           0           1         0
96         1           0           0         0
97         1           0           0         0
98         0           0           0         1
99         0           0           0         1

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

※ところで、0～20、21～40、41～60 という分け方だと、それぞれに含まれる年齢が 21 個、20 個、20 個となってしまいますがこれであっていますか？　0～19、20～39、40～59 の方が適切そうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに分け方としては記載なさっている方法の方が綺麗ですね。apply関数というものを初めて知りました、ご参考にさせていただきます。